# Firefox wants to connect to crowdcache1.stonekitty.net on TCP port 9911 (sype-transport)?

Tags: macos, firefox, security, firewall, little-snitch

I just installed Little Snitch on my Mac. When I start up Firefox it now popups with the above warning.

I can't seem to find any information regarding sype-transport or port 9911, beyond that it is used for SypeCom transport protocol.

Anybody can help enlighten me?

Comment: (As an aside: your user name prohibits @user comment reply notifications. See [How do comment @replies work?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work) for details.)

Comment: Could be a firefox addon. Try disabling them all then re-enabling till it appears again.

Comment: @mrstatic - hmm i doubt it, i just have adblock plus, web developer and firebug.... i have many more including these installed on other computers and don't see this behaviour....

Comment: So, where did you download your copy of Firefox?

Comment: @arjan: original from mozilla. then the updates got from the ff update manager.

Answer (score 0):

crowdcache1.stonekitty.net appeared in the download for Firefox 3.6.13.I DID NOT run the file!Instead, My security software scanned the file and tagged it a "ZOMBIE": a file that
terminates itself so as not to alarm anti-virus programs. It can, under certain conditions on your computer, launch malicious code from a remote hacker.
When I tried to download Firefox 3.6.13 again, Mozilla's name as publisher was on the download AS IT SHOULD BE! How crowdcache1.stonekitty.net got there is a question for Mozilla.
You may well have a malware infection.

Comment: hmmm that's scary.... :( question asked on mozillazine forums. thanks for the reply Big Jim.   http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=38&t=2058431

Answer (score 0):

It appears it is/was/could have been a mirror site for Mozilla?

For instance, this page http://mytopfiles.com/programs/file/Firefox-Setup-4-0/431156.htm  shows stonekitty.net & below various mirrors.  (It does not show the particular port.)

I picked one of the mirrors, "saudi.net.sa".

Going here, http://www.mozilla.org/community/mirrors.html, I find neither "stonekitty" nor "saudi".

Though viewing the source of the page, I do find, "href="http://mozilla.saudi.net.sa", so you would expect that to be legit?

Perhaps stonekitty was at one time a mirror?

In any case, what I surmise above proves nothing.

Do you still have the downloaded file?  If so, you can easily verify its validity, ftp://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/3.6.13/SHA1SUMS.

(And in any case, 3.6.13 is dated & you should update to 3.6.17.)

Comment: I just ran into this too. Very weird. Stonekitty is listed at that mirror site though as a secondary mirror. Not that I trust them with my browser.